# How to remove droplets of paint on my car?

Tags: paint, cleaning

I'm not sure if its paint or cement, but my car is covered with droplets of it. I had my car washed, but its still there. Its removable if you scrape it with your nail. Is there any liquid material that I could wipe on it to take it off? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you try something like [Turtle Wax Bug & Tar Remover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009JKGII). Not knowing exactly what the substance is on your finish, I'd start light and go stronger from there. The Bug & Tar stuff will do it's thing without damaging your paint finish. As you get more involved in what you are trying to do to remove the substance, the greater risk you'll have in damaging the finish. I'm not sure a clay bar will work, mainly because it's usually used on grime of a finer nature than what you are talking about. I wouldn't exclude it from what you try and it won't damage your finish, but will probably take some elbow grease to get it to work. You may also try waxing these areas, as wax gets under/around the contaminant, it will get it to release. Just be aware of whatever you do, to continually change out your cloth or use clean areas of the cloth. If you don't, you run the risk of scratching your finish by rubbing the contaminants back and around everything (hope that makes sense).

Comment: You could also add very soft tools (used with great care) to the mix. If they're coming off with a fingernail, a clay bar on its own probably won't do it. I have [non-marring tools](http://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/Plastic-Opening-Tools/IF145-000) that I use in my other life that could be used to carefully work them loose. You might also want to use [cleaner wax](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/8739/57) for its very mild abrasive effect.

Comment: I wouldn't discount the clay bar option. This has become my go-to method of removing stuff like tar spots, bugs, etc. In my experience, it can remove some pretty hard-stuck stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I just had my car accidentally, lightly over-sprayed near a construction zone entering the US at at the Mexicali POE where the building contractor working on their facility didn't know how to control the spray adjacent to the traffic lane. The upper parts of my car had hundreds of small spots on it. I'm not sure if it was solvent or water based paint, but it was an exterior coating for the building. When I got home 3 hours later in over 100 degree heat I used bug and tar remover to lubricate and slightly soften the spots. After using my fingernail for a while I switched to a small stick of hardwood with sharply-cut corners. I used the end of the stick (about 1/4" x 3/8") and the long sides (about 8"). It worked pretty well, but it also took about an hour's worth of elbow grease.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you employ test on an old junker with the same problem 1st rather than damage your paintwork further