# How to remove latex over spray from my 89 Honda

Tags: paint

I painted my house last year and got some water base Latex paint over spray on my 89 Honda, any ideas how to soften and remove it other than a polisher?

The paint on this Honda does not have a clear coat and is the original White paint.

Comment: Related, but not so much to call it a duplicate: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/8838/12030

Comment: did any of these answers work?

Comment: Sold the car before I attempted any.

Answer (score 5):

There are products which can remove it for you. [Here is an example](http://www.parish-supply.com/latex-paint-remover.aspx), though I don't know if it will *specifically not damage* painted surfaces, as it states it is for hard surfaces. I know there are also some wipes out there which will do the same.

[image]

Of course, once the latex is dried, it becomes much harder to remove. You'll also need to consider replenishing the wax coating onto the surface of the paint, as whatever you use will be sure to strip all of it off, leaving the surface unprotected.

Comment: "It is great for removing surfaces with over spray. This biodegradable and water based product is designed to work safely on all types of hard surfaces." Sounds safe to me, I will look for something similar in my area.

Answer (score 4):

I soften the paint with brake cleaner. Dampen a rag with brake clean and then rub gently for 60 seconds or less. Then use a medium cutting compound on a random orbit polisher. For thick deposits several applications may be needed. Wait a few minutes between tries to let the solvent flash off. Test the brake clean on a out of the way spot first to see if the paint will tolerate the process. The older the latex paint the harder it gets and therefore it takes longer to soften.
 It is usually required to polish the whole car due to the difference in luster of the cleaned area.