# Hit a wall with my car how to remove paint?

Tags: paint, cosmetic

Hit a wall with my door handle. What's the best way to remove paint?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is an ideal situation for some [cleaner wax](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/8766/57).  It will have a mild polish to lift the extra paint and wax to reduce the impact of the mark on your eyes.

I'm looking at that scuff and it really looks like you just barely kissed whatever left the white mark.  If you wash the handle really well, you'll be surprised how well a little cleaner wax will help.

Remember, though, any sort of polishing requires patience.

Comment: I got a similar paint mark on my car body after brushing lightly against a gate. Rubbing the area with a wet cloth appeared to get some of the paint onto the cloth, but I'm afraid the water might corrode any tiny sections where the car paint itself got scratched off to expose the metal. Is corrosion a risk? Or do I first use the wet cloth and then use the wax to ensure that oxygen does not reach the metal?

Comment: @Nav, if the mark left by the gate is coming off with water and a cloth, that's great. However, make sure that you rinse (and probably wash with car soap) the area really well before you start. There's likely some extra dirt and grit  in the area and you don't want to rub that *into* your paint while you're rubbing the gate paint off. With respect to corrosion, you can't really know until you clean up the mark. At that point, you can fix any remaining problems.

Comment: Thanks Bob. A use of detergent soap and wet cloth got rid of the paint.

Answer (score 0):

paint thinners or acetone applied sparingly with a soft cloth should do the trick.Nail
polish remover is also effective

Answer (score 0):

I used goo-gone and it worked perfectly!!