# What should I use to remove spray paint

Tags: paint

Some people, presumably kids, spray painted my windows and other parts of my car the other weekend. I took the critical area's (the windows) off with a razor blade paint scraper. How can I get the rest of the spray paint off without damaging the cars actual paint?

Comment: I'd try, in a less conspicuous spot, using orange cleaner. This volatile oil derived from orange skin dissolves paint. I little on a white (not green or black) plastic scourer and a little scrubbing. Then rinse off with water to remove orange oil so it does not work on your car's paint. Actually, I'd try white scourer on it's own first.

Answer (score 3):

[The first thing that I usually try in situations like this is some cleaner wax](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/8766/57) (e.g., some [Zymol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009JKIRC) - it's cheap, cheerful and smells nice):

I'm pretty pleased with the procedure that I outlined in the attached "door ding" answer.  The most important point, though, is that **patience is key**.  You're almost certainly super annoyed at this situation (I'm annoyed and it's not even my car!) but you're going to have to accept that slow and careful progress is much better than making the problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

A professional quality re-finish would mean stripping the affected paint work back to bare metal and a re-spray, but not always. Firstly, try on a small area of the effected paint work an application of regular domestic oven cleaner. Leave it on for only the time it takes to soften the spray paint and rinse off the emulsion produced straight away with clean water. Use a pair of protective gloves to keep the oven cleaner off of your hands. With the spray paint removed polish the paint work of the car with car polish. This works on most car finishes.

Comment: Oven cleaner? What kind?

Comment: I am UK based and a popular brand is 'Mr Muscle'. It is what house-wives use on the home oven.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used brake parts cleaner. It shouldn't harm dried clear coat factory paint. Any other paint will be annihilated, though. Alternatives are acetone, paint thinner, gasoline. I'd use extra care with those 3.

(some other people with personal experience using these)

http://www.corvetteforum.com/forums/off-topic/2132418-will-carb-cleaner-or-brake-cleaner-hurt-paint.html

https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/1dbx41/lpt_removing_spraypaint_from_your_car_applied_and/

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please post the relational information instead of just citing links to other sites.  If those links were to ever go down your answer could be removed and/or downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a light application of T-Cut or cutting paste.  Be very careful just to take the new paint off.  It should make fairly light work of new spray paint.